# Core animation progress callback

Tags: ios, core-animation

Is there an easy way to be called back when a Core Animation reaches certain points as it's running (for example, at 50% and 66% of completion ?

I'm currently thinking about setting up an NSTimer, but that's not really as accurate as I'd like.

Comment: I don't know about easy... but how's about KVO on the property that you are manipulating.... it rings a bell that I might have done this before.

Comment: At certain points during the animation I want to display and hide other views.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've finally developed a solution for this problem.

Essentially I wish to be called back for every frame and do what I need to do.

There's no obvious way to observe the progress of an animation, however it is actually possible:

- Firstly we need to create a new subclass of CALayer that has an animatable property called 'progress'.
- We add the layer into our tree, and then create an animation that will drive the progress value from 0 to 1 over the duration of the animation.
- Since our progress property can be animated, drawInContext is called on our sublass for every frame of an animation. This function doesn't need to redraw anything, however it can be used to call a delegate function :)

Here's the class interface:

```
@protocol TAProgressLayerProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)progressUpdatedTo:(CGFloat)progress;

@end

@interface TAProgressLayer : CALayer

@property CGFloat progress;
@property (weak) id<TAProgressLayerProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation TAProgressLayer

// We must copy across our custom properties since Core Animation makes a copy
// of the layer that it's animating.

- (id)initWithLayer:(id)layer
{
    self = [super initWithLayer:layer];
    if (self) {
        TAProgressLayer *otherLayer = (TAProgressLayer *)layer;
        self.progress = otherLayer.progress;
        self.delegate = otherLayer.delegate;
    }
    return self;
}

// Override needsDisplayForKey so that we can define progress as being animatable.

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString*)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"progress"]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
    }
}

// Call our callback

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate progressUpdatedTo:self.progress];
    }
}

@end
```

We can then add the layer to our main layer:

```
TAProgressLayer *progressLayer = [TAProgressLayer layer];
progressLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, -1, 1, 1);
progressLayer.delegate = self;
[_sceneView.layer addSublayer:progressLayer];
```

And animate it along with the other animations:

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"progress"];
anim.duration = 4.0;
anim.beginTime = 0;
anim.fromValue = @0;
anim.toValue = @1;
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[progressLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"progress"];
```

Finally, the delegate will be called back as the animation progresses:

```
- (void)progressUpdatedTo:(CGFloat)progress
{
    // Do whatever you need to do...
}
```

Comment: Nice work. Note that you have to remove the animation from the layer explicitly when its done, otherwise drawInContext: will not stop getting called on every frame.

Comment: Awesome idea. I'd like to suggest a small improvement. You're currently forced to set the layer's frame to a 1x1 rect since `drawInContext:` isn't called unless the layer's frame is non-zero (creating a 1x1pt bitmap in the process). Instead you can override `[CALayer display]`, which _will_ be called for a zero frame, and won't create a bitmap context by default (marginally more efficient). The only difference is that you'd need to read `self.presentationLayer.progress` instead of `self.progress` within the `draw` implementation.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to hack a CALayer to report progress to you, there's another approach. Conceptually, you can use a CADisplayLink to guarantee a callback on each frame, and then simply measure the time that has passed since the start of the animation divided by the duration to figure out the percent complete.

The open source library [INTUAnimationEngine](https://github.com/intuit/AnimationEngine) packages this functionality up very cleanly into an API that looks almost exactly like the UIView block-based animation one:

```
// INTUAnimationEngine.h

// ...

+ (NSInteger)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                           delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
                      animations:(void (^)(CGFloat percentage))animations
                      completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;

// ...
```

All you need to do is call this method at the same time you start other animation(s), passing the same values for `duration` and `delay`, and then for each frame of the animation the `animations` block will be executed with the current percent complete. And if you want peace of mind that your timings are perfectly synchronized, you can drive your animations exclusively from INTUAnimationEngine.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The current accepted answer seems like a hack in comparison. This tutorial explains how to setup a basic CADisplayLink scheme: https://zearfoss.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/more-cadisplaylink/  You can also apply easing quite easily your self to this scheme. Try this tutorial to understand the basics of applying easing to FPS animation: https://medium.com/thoughts-on-thoughts/recreating-apple-s-rubber-band-effect-in-swift-dbf981b40f35#.tpbvwo1wi

Comment: this tutorial also favours the CADisplayLink approach over the current accepted answer. http://holko.pl/2014/06/26/recreating-skypes-action-sheet-animation/

Answer (score 6):

I made a Swift (2.0) implementation of the CALayer subclass suggested by tarmes in the accepted answer:

```
protocol TAProgressLayerProtocol {

    func progressUpdated(progress: CGFloat)

}

class TAProgressLayer : CALayer {

    // MARK: - Progress-related properties

    var progress: CGFloat = 0.0
    var progressDelegate: TAProgressLayerProtocol? = nil

    // MARK: - Initialization & Encoding

    // We must copy across our custom properties since Core Animation makes a copy
    // of the layer that it's animating.

    override init(layer: AnyObject) {
        super.init(layer: layer)
        if let other = layer as? TAProgressLayerProtocol {
            self.progress = other.progress
            self.progressDelegate = other.progressDelegate
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        progressDelegate = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("progressDelegate") as? CALayerProgressProtocol
        progress = CGFloat(aDecoder.decodeFloatForKey("progress"))
    }

    override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)
        aCoder.encodeFloat(Float(progress), forKey: "progress")
        aCoder.encodeObject(progressDelegate as! AnyObject?, forKey: "progressDelegate")
    }

    init(progressDelegate: TAProgressLayerProtocol?) {
        super.init()
        self.progressDelegate = progressDelegate
    }

    // MARK: - Progress Reporting

    // Override needsDisplayForKey so that we can define progress as being animatable.
    class override func needsDisplayForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
        if (key == "progress") {
            return true
        } else {
            return super.needsDisplayForKey(key)
        }
    }

    // Call our callback

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
        if let del = self.progressDelegate {
            del.progressUpdated(progress)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Ported to Swift 4.2:

```
protocol CAProgressLayerDelegate: CALayerDelegate {
    func progressDidChange(to progress: CGFloat)
}

extension CAProgressLayerDelegate {
    func progressDidChange(to progress: CGFloat) {}
}

class CAProgressLayer: CALayer {
    private struct Const {
        static let animationKey: String = "progress"
    }

    @NSManaged private(set) var progress: CGFloat
    private var previousProgress: CGFloat?
    private var progressDelegate: CAProgressLayerDelegate? { return self.delegate as? CAProgressLayerDelegate }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init()
        self.frame = frame
    }

    override init(layer: Any) {
        super.init(layer: layer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.progress = CGFloat(aDecoder.decodeFloat(forKey: Const.animationKey))
    }

    override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        super.encode(with: aCoder)
        aCoder.encode(Float(self.progress), forKey: Const.animationKey)
    }

    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        if key == Const.animationKey { return true }
        return super.needsDisplay(forKey: key)
    }

    override func display() {
        super.display()
        guard let layer: CAProgressLayer = self.presentation() else { return }
        self.progress = layer.progress
        if self.progress != self.previousProgress {
            self.progressDelegate?.progressDidChange(to: self.progress)
        }
        self.previousProgress = self.progress
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
class ProgressView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAProgressLayer.self
    }
}

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, CAProgressLayerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let progressView = ProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        progressView.layer.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(progressView)

        var animations = [CAAnimation]()

        let opacityAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        opacityAnimation.fromValue = 0
        opacityAnimation.toValue = 1
        opacityAnimation.duration = 1
        animations.append(opacityAnimation)

        let progressAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "progress")
        progressAnimation.fromValue = 0
        progressAnimation.toValue = 1
        progressAnimation.duration = 1
        animations.append(progressAnimation)

        let group = CAAnimationGroup()
        group.duration = 1
        group.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        group.animations = animations

        progressView.layer.add(group, forKey: nil)
    }

    func progressDidChange(to progress: CGFloat) {
        print(progress)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)