# Swift: Change label text value as animation plays

Tags: ios, swift

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578023/animate-drawing-of-a-circle) answer to create an animated circle, and it works just fine. In addition to the path, I draw a text in the center of the view with **drawInRect**. I would like that text to change during the animation, to reflect the percentage of the path that is visible at each moment. How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most promising post would likely be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827973/core-animation-progress-callback) one. It describes creating a new `CALayer` that keeps track of the progress, which can then fire a call back.

Otherwise you'll likely need to wangle something together by observing your view's `presentationLayer`.